# Tab Screens Missing for React-Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, tabs

I am using the package react-native-tab-view to render a tab widget in the middle of the screen.  The widget renders correctly on iOS but the screens are missing on Android.  This widget appears in the middle of the screen with material both above and below it and all of it is wrapped in a ScrollView something like this (additional material not shown for brevity):

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: primaryLightBlue2Color }}>
        <View style={{paddingVertical: 10}}>
            <MemberSummary />
            <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />

            <TabView
                navigationState={this.state}
                renderScene={this.renderScene}
                renderTabBar={this.renderTabBar}
                onIndexChange={this.handleIndexChange}
                tabStyle={styles.tabbar}
            />

            {this.spendingAccountsExist()}
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

As I mentioned, the screens associated with the tabs do not display[image: see attached]

so, am I doing something wrong that they do not display or is the widget not designed for what I am attempting to do?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer which can be found here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/issues/537#issuecomment-395359494

To summarize, for Android, make sure that your TabView component has renderPager like this:

```
_renderPager = (props) => <PagerPan {...props} />
```

and

```
<TabView
    navigationState={this.state}
    renderScene={this._renderScene}
    renderTabBar={this._renderTabBar}
    onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
    renderPager={this._renderPager}
    tabStyle={styles.tabbar}
/>
```

Comment: This worked for me, didn't had `renderPager` on my code, thanks

Comment: Where do you import PagerPan from ?